# How do i architect microservices and an API globally?

Tags: api, architecture, api-design

I had a question regarding global availability of an API and performance. Basically, we would like to build an API that is central to our business, but it must be highly available and performant globally, meaning, response times of the API should be minimal whether the call is being made in the United States, China, or any other country in the world. The API is actually an interface into a microservice architecture that is domain driven. We are currently using Microsoft Azure as our cloud provider to host these microservices but I wanted to get some suggestions on architecting a solution that makes this performant across the globe. Would we need to deploy services in multiple regions to be able to make this work? If so, how would I route an incoming request to the appropriate region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would partition your data by region using username as the partition key.  Distribute your microservices and databases around the world in appropriate places, but keep one central login service.  As users register with your central registration service, you assign them to a region depending on their home address, IP, or some other geographical indicator.  When they return to login the second time (using the central service), you authenticate them and pull their region from the central DB.  You can now route all additional traffic to the proper region for the best performance.

You would have to implement a full set of domains in each region.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What if users need to access all data, not just the data that is partitioned for them?

Comment: I'm afraid your only option is replication of all data.  MS and AWS both offer this service. You can search for Azure Geo-redundant storage to read about their version.  I don't know what their SLA is for replication, but would guess it's within a second or two.

Comment: Thank you @Brad Irby. I appreciate the help.